# Is potentially dangerous to select the take-off power on airliner lower that temperature at the moment on the airport?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, pilot-technique

Is potentially dangerous to select the take-off power on airliner at lower settings  value due to the temperature that could be increased by the time the aircraft will go up?

Comment: Are you talking about "flex thrust"?

Comment: Yes for Airbus this is the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about flex thrust, then NO - it is not at all a problem. It is basically a FAKE temperature which the pilots provide the FADEC with so that the FADEC purposely reduces the amount of thrust generated by the engine. This can improve engine lift by reducing wear. But remember, PILOT'S ARE NOT SUPPOSED TO USE FLEX THRUST DURING ROUGH WEATHER. They are supposed to to Firewall their engine (TOGA detent), as they would definetly need max thrust.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not dangerous.  Flex thrust simply exploits all of the runway available, taking advantage of any length that is surplus to the minimum required at max thrust, to allow takeoff with less than maximum thrust to save wear and tear and fuel (wear and tear is a big deal taking off in a sandy/dusty environment and use of flex has a significant effect on engine life).

The fact that you are using "just enough power" for a flex takeoff does not change the technical risks.  The balanced field length requirements (accelerate/stop and accelerate/go safely) are still met, so the extra length available in a non-flex takeoff does not technically speaking, reduce the risks of something going wrong following an engine failure on takeoff or following a reject.

Comment: Isn't FLEX setting OAT _higher_ than the actual OAT to obtain reduced thrust?

Comment: Yes with flex you set power to give performance equivalent to a higher operating temperature, the "assumed temperature", being the hottest temp at which you can make a departure at max thrust on a given runway for your weight.  You need runway analysis charts for the departure airport to do it. His question is a bit incoherent in its phrasing (language difficulty) and I think he is just asking are there risks to using flex.  Anyway that's the assumption upon which my answer is based.

Comment: Yes, that is my question, if there's anything  can go wrong due derating thrust?

Comment: @georgegeo if this is your question, you may edit your initial question to reflect it. It is ok to make the description evolve since it adds clarifications